# Create a column in a Pandas DataFrame that counts all rows greater or less than the current row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, countif

I have a DataFrame that includes a Player, Salary and Score and am looking to flag entries where the Salary is higher, and Score is lower than any other Players in the DataFrame.

I am a python novice, so I am probably way off in how I'm thinking about this.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([['A',12000,100],['B',13000,110],['C',13300,105],['D',12500,102],['E',11800,101]],columns=['Player','Salary','Score'])

df['OverPriced']= (df['Score'].iloc[:]>df['Score'] & df['Salary'].iloc[:]<df['Salary']).count()

Print(df)
```

I would like to see something like the following:

```
    Player  Salary  Score   Overpriced
0   A       12000     100         1
1   B       13000     110         0
2   C       13300     105         1
3   D       12500     102         0
4   E       11800     101         0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `numpy` broadcast here , and with `any`

```
import numpy as np
s1=df.Salary.values
s2=df.Score.values
df['Overpriced']=np.any((s1>s1[:,None])&(s2<s2[:,None]),0).astype(int)
df
Out[377]: 
  Player  Salary  Score  Overpriced
0      A   12000    100           1
1      B   13000    110           0
2      C   13300    105           1
3      D   12500    102           0
4      E   11800    101           0
```

Comment: Sorry, this actually doesn't return the correct answer.  I would expect 'A' and 'C' to flag up as overpriced as there are other options that are cheaper and deliver a higher score (B > C, and E > A)

Comment: Fixed by switching around the <>  symbols.  Thanks again.

Comment: @JarrodHolmes check the update , I type it wrong , change np.any from 1 to 0